# Is this behavior of "any" a TypeScript Type System Bug?

Tags: typescript

I expect the TypeScript compiler to fail given this code:

```
function test(f: string) {
    console.log(typeof f);
}

const foo: any = ["Test"];
test(foo);

const boo = "test";
test(boo);
```

The output is:

```
object
string
```

I am hesitant to write a bug on GitHub as I am not TypeScript expert. What do folks think?

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCmALkRgJxjAHMBKRAbwChE7EIE04AbFAOhbhMygE8ADijjBEwMgG5qAX2rVGYDGLhw8AQzB9EAXkQBtAEQAVdFAMBdKagzYVkuQqUAjFTsQHrZq6cwu49oA)

Comment: The whole point of `any` is to disable TypeScript's type checking when you need to. Working as intended as far as I can tell.

Comment: Where do you expect it to fail?  At `test(foo);`? But you’ve annotated `foo` as `any` which intentionally turns off type checking.  You generally shouldn’t use `any` anywhere you want type safety.

Comment: I see, thanks! Then as the designer of an API, `function test(f: string)`  doesn't really guarantee that `f` is of type `string`. IMO, this is not great, but again this is objective.

Comment: If the API needs to absolutely 100% guarantee that it's a string, then check `typeof` and throw an error if it fails or something like that. Otherwise, the developer should know that using `any` puts them at risk of things like this happening. All languages I know of have unsafe "use at your own risk" features, TypeScript isn't any different.

Comment: If we are going to be writing typeof, we might as well go back to writing JavaScript. IMO, this defeats the purpose of the type annotation.

Comment: Again, that's the entire point. Don't use `any` unless you *want* to ignore type annotation. What's the point of having seat belts in a car if you can just unbuckle them?

Comment: Since data can come from external sources (input, network) and TS is a compile time language no matter how strict you design TS, it could never guarantee runtime types anyway.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I understand the `any` construct and I am not claiming that you shouldn't have unsafe constructs in the language, I am actually all for it. What I disagree with is that this code is actually lying to the reader.

For example, 
`function test(f: string) { console.log(f[0]); }`
This will prints the full string instead of the first character and to me this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is to opt out of type checking for some parts of your code.  It is intentionally unsound; all types are assignable to `any` and `any` is assignable to all types (except for `never`).  This is both useful and dangerous.  Useful because there are times where it tedious, difficult, or impossible to properly type a piece of valid real-world code, and `any` is an escape hatch.  Dangerous because the compiler cannot tell the difference between *valid* code typed with `any` and *invalid* code typed with `any`. So in general the advice for `any` is "use it sparingly".

If you don't find such advice sufficient because you don't trust others or yourself not to write code like `test(foo)` above, then there is at least one option you might explore before throwing TypeScript away entirely: [linting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

[TypeScript ESLint](https://typescript-eslint.io/) can be configured to disallow annotating a value as type `any` via the [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/348d2f6b207acb9e18721cba53f0aa85908fa777/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) rule.  This would cause you to get an error something like this:

```
// TypeScript ESLint
const foo: any = ["Test"];
// -----> ~~~~
// warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type
// @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```