# Why don't Parameters<Func> extend unknown[] (Array<unknown>) in ts strict mode

Tags: typescript, types, arguments, extends, spread-syntax

The title pretty much says it all really. I have this code:

```
  type testNoArgsF = () => number;
  type testArgsF = (arg1: boolean, arg2: string) => number;
  type unknownArgsF = (...args: unknown[]) => number;
  type anyArgsF = (...args: any[]) => number;

  type testII = testArgsF extends anyArgsF ? true : false; // true
  type testIII = Parameters<testArgsF> extends Parameters<unknownArgsF>
    ? true
    : false; // true

  // unexpected:
  type testIV = testArgsF extends unknownArgsF ? true : false; // false <- why?
  // even though:
  type testV = testNoArgsF extends unknownArgsF ? true : false; // true
```

It is written in typescript (version 3.8), and I have strict mode enabled. The unexpected result is that a test function doesn't extend a function type with spread args of `unknown[]`, yet if you just check the parameters they **do** extend `unknown[]`. Since the return type is always number, I don't understand what else could possibly be different to falsify the `extends` statement.

Other notes:

- The extend statement is true only if your test function has 0 arguments.
- This behaviour is not seen if you turn off strict mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [`--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled, function type parameters are checked *contravariantly*. "Contra-variant" means that the subtype relationship of the function varies in the opposite direction from that of function parameters.  So if `A extends B`, then `(x: B)=>void extends (x: A)=>void` *and not vice-versa*.

This is a type safety issue due to the nature of "substitutability" in TypeScript, also known as [behavioral subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_subtyping).  If `A extends B` is true, you should be able to use an `A` as a `B`.  If you can't, then `A extends B` is not true.

If you turn off `--strict` then the compiler uses the pre-TS-2.6 behavior of checking function parameters *bivariantly*, which is unsafe, but was allowed for reasons of productivity.  That might be off-topic here, but you can read more about it in the TypeScript FAQ entry for ["Why are function parameters bivariant?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)

---

Anyway, if you need a function type that accepts any number `unknown` parameters, you cannot safely use a function that only a specific subtype of `unknown`.  Observe:

```
const t: testArgsF = (b, s) => (b ? s.trim() : s).length
const u: unknownArgsF = t; // error!

u(1, 2, 3); // explosion at runtime! s.trim is not a function
```

If `testArgsF extends unknownArgsF` were true, then you would be able to assign `t` to `u` above without error, leading immediately to runtime errors when `u` happily accepts a non-`string` second argument.

You can see that the only safe way to subtype/implement a function type is for the subtype/implementation to accept arguments that are the same or *wider* than those expected by the supertype/call-signature.  That's why `--strictFunctionTypes` was introduced to the language.

---

If you change `unknown` to `any` (using `anyArgsF` instead of `unknownArgsF`) then the compiler will not complain *because `any` is [intentionally unsound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59315017/2887218) in TypeScript*.  The type `any` is considered to be assignable both *to* and *from* every other type; that's unsafe because, for example `string extends any` and `any extends number` are both true while `string extends number` is false.  The substitution principle above is therefore not enforced when `any` is involved.  Annotating a value as the `any` type is equivalent to loosening or turning off type checking for that value.   That doesn't save you from the runtime error; it just silences the compiler's error:

```
const a: anyArgsF = t; // okay, type checking with any is disabled/loosened
a(1, 2, 3); // same explosion at runtime!
```

---

In the case where `testNoArgsF extends unknownArgsF` is true, this is also a consequence of substitutability.  You can use a function that takes no arguments as if it were just about any function type, since it will (usually) end up ignoring any arguments passed into it:

```
const n: testNoArgsF = () => 1;
const u2: unknownArgsF = n; // okay
u2(1, 2, 3); // okay at runtime, since `n` ignores its arguments
```

This is explained in the TypeScript FAQ entry ["Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7AHIHsCCAnA5nAYlAvFABQCUBAfFAHYCuAtgEYToDcAUKJDPMBtnoSIBDLAEYAXFAbJkAGwhCqAGigjMAJkkJ0ASyqYy+SrUbN2naDSoBrKsgDuVPrgLEAdB7VxJV2w6oA2gC6hsb0TKwc4NCKIM4C7p5Y3qpUIMGh1OFmbFFcsAgAkoWuBbzJeBAAHrBUACZwqXEVUAD8MOg00JIAZkKycBAsUAD0Ix1dedBlxSWEAAoiQnQQsOhwADxl8ZTVtQ1Qi+jLq8ybvnaOO2xQbRMQN1C9-YPDY-e571bVkADGsHVxFNuEUAGqlHjxKB7CD1RoXfxQ9rATrdKB9AZDUbjDGDKAbAC0UHsAAsQK02O8IAA3WEwEnIGiYElAiwg4DgwhlFBQmFwqAIq4tZGop7ol5Y94oya5X7IKgIGCSbYtQQMFRwTJEBh3OBuFE6OikMWatzyfTAElsOUK4ACnw2S5OVUwN7jZjoZDoACEbBoRFEKnUKgAzCQ3dCqmBZMg4Dp5ao7Z0qMBDRBvVA9Qa6FAdI07HahOirP941RZfLFUJJLEoVyI8hrEIQGwhAGg6Hw9jI9HY2XE1Bk6mVr6K7bqMqeDyXcajFBROwbYqaJoBY7ES6qA2my2V+2oMGoGHt82B0O0xq9L9oAADKg33OYOzoeC54CNNT0WHvoA)

Comment: I guess the difference between parameter types and function types, and the reason they are contravariant could be understood intuitively though this reasoning: when you're stating a function type you're saying what you're giving, whereas when you're stating a parameter type you're saying what you're receiving (and you/your function has to handle all eventualities).

Comment: Does that mean that the only way to specify a generic function template type is as `(...args: any[]) => any`? It's just that I had read you should always try and avoid `any` if possible, so was trying to use `unknown` instead.

Comment: The reason not to use `any` is that it disables some type checking. But most of the other ways you might try to describe "some function" do this too. `Function` and `(...args: never[])=>unknown` will match any function but allow [unsound calls](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31698#issuecomment-497775868) ([see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFADwFw2gJwJZgDmAlEgHwxoB0UIAqgA4MCmOAwgIYTMrEDcAKFCRYhLADEArmGBQ84JPEHDoMABZYUVbZhhhmAN1YBtALqlEFaQGswIAO5hFcQQMK8+MAPReYIEAwQAmoe3r7+gW4oAIwANDAATPEAzPxhMABGeIR+AUECQA)). So it's up to your use case, really.

Comment: My use-case was defining a generic function type `Func` to use as a base generic type requirement in the function `const apply = <F extends Func>(func: F, ...params: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> => func(...params);`. This was needed to call a union-of-functions typed variable, even though the appropriate parameters were provided (this was within a modifier for a library of similar functions). But it sounds like the type coercion/unsafe aspect of `any` is actually needed here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to put it simple: "extends" -> "compatible" -> "can be used in place of"

Can you use `(arg1: boolean, arg2: string) => number;`
instead of `(...args: unknown[]) => number`?

No, because the latter can handle call without arguments, but the former might fail at runtime (e.g. will try to access properties of the arguments)

More info on functions compatibility [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)

Answer (score 1):

```
type testIV = testArgsF extends unknownArgsF ? true : false; // false 
type testIVa = unknownArgsF extends testArgsF  ? true : false; // true!

// because
type testIII = Parameters<testArgsF> extends Parameters<unknownArgsF>
    ? true
    : false; // true
```

Extends really means 'is assignable to'.
And `f(p:A)=>` is assignable to `f(p:B)=>` if B is assignable to A. I think it's called 'contravariant'.

```
// Imagine your function expects callback that has some type as a paramter:

var f = (cb: ({ a, b }: { a: number, b: number }) => void) => { cb({ a:1, b: 1}); };

// you can safely call it giving it the function that accepts parameter 
// that the original parameter is assignable to but not the other way around
// because that's the way to guarantee that when our function f calls the callback
// it will provide sufficient amount of data
f(({ a }: { a: number }) => { })


var x = { a: 1, b: 1 };
var y = { a: 1 }

x = y; // error because x would have no b property after that assignment
y = x; // works because y has all it needs after that assignment and it doesn't matter it has property b too

// in other words:
type F = { a: number } extends { a: number, b: number } ? true : false; // false
type T = { a: number, b: number } extends { a: number } ? true : false; // true

// read 'extends' as 'is assignable to'
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your four-line comment in the second block of code... can't quite work out if I'm being silly or whether it's a bit unclear/convoluted! Not to worry though, I think I got the gist