# Is there a way to disable comparison any vs other type?

Tags: typescript, coercion, type-coercion

Typescript has pretty cool error message on checking different types:

```js
let strange_boolean = true;
let strange_string: string = "1";
console.log(strange_boolean == strange_string);
```

```
error: TS2367 [ERROR]: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean' and 'string' have no overlap.
console.log(strange_boolean == strange_string);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For but this code compiles:

```js
let strange_boolean: any = true;
let strange_string: string = "1";
console.log(strange_boolean == strange_string);
```

Because `any` can be converted to `anything` ...

But what if I want somehow to disable even implicit conversion from `any` to anything ?
Is `Typescript` has any flag for that ?
I want that this code compiles only in that case:

```js
let strange_boolean: any = true;
let strange_string: string = "1";
console.log(String(strange_boolean) == strange_string);
```

or

```js
let strange_boolean: any = true;
let strange_string: string = "1";
console.log(Boolean(strange_boolean) == Boolean(strange_string));
```

Comment: I've not written much TypeScript lately, but maybe the `unknown` type helps here?

Comment: @JoachimSauer What is unknown type ... and actually it works even for this strange type ... But I want to disable working code like any == string ... I want only explicit actions, explicit conversions

Comment: Since `==` is reference comparison I don't think there's a straightforward way to achieve what you want, but `unknown` is similar to `any`  except that while `any` is "this could be anything so you can do whatever with it", `unknown` is more "this could be anything so you need to check what it is before doing anything with it".

Comment: Related: ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51439843)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I just want to prevent implicit conversions ;) `==` it is reference comparison only in case if it is the same object, but what if it is another object ? I want at compile time prevent such comparasion with comile error

Comment: The TS compiler doesn't do this for you, but if you use a linter like ESLint you could use a rule like [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a TypeScript Type System Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313928/is-this-a-typescript-type-system-bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such possibility at the current moment ... (

I have created issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39209, but it was closed, because Typescript team do not want break backward comparability for `any` and it is unfortunate, because if they will add this flag then code become more safe than in "Vanilla" JavaScript