# TypeScript error during method overriding: Overriding vs Overloading

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 classes I am using as services in angular 9: class A and class B, class B extends A

```
class A{
 exportToCSV(data: any[], headers: any[]){
      ....
   }

}


class B extends A{
 exportToCSV(data: any[], headers: any[], metadata : any){
      ....
   }

}
```

It throws this error:

> **Property 'exportToCSV' in type 'B' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A'.
> Type '(data: any[], headers: any[], metadata : any) => void' is not assignable to type '(data: any[], headers: any[]) => void'.ts(2416)**

Based on the documents https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

this should work, but it doesn't. If I make the metadata optional however, it works (https://medium.com/@kevinkreuzer/typescript-method-overloading-c256dd63245a).

I am trying to override the method but instead it's overloading the method. Can someone explain why this is happening ?

Comment: how can this be overriding when you have more parameters in child class ? so this is a pure case of overloading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a case of [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), which in TypeScript means that a function or method may be called with multiple distinct call signatures, and whose (single) implementation  must be compatible with all of them.  Here your `B` class has a `exportToCSV()` method with a single call signature and implementation; no overloading here.  This is just overriding (albeit an illegal override).

---

So you are overriding the `exportToCSV()` method from `A` with one from `B`.  The problem is that the signature for `B`'s method violates the contract from `A`.  The basic principle involved in determining compatibility is [substitutability (or the Liskov Substituion Principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if `B extends A` is true, then you should be able to use a `B` in place of an `A`.  If I ask for an `A`, and you hand me a `B`, I should be able to use it like an `A` without having anything blow up.  Meaning the following line should be fine:

```
const a: A = new B(); // okay if B really extends A
a.exportToCSV([], []); // also okay if B really extends A
```

Things are a little murky because you've given the `metadata` parameter the [intentionally unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59315017/2887218) `any` type, but if it were a regular type, it would be dangerous to do this.  Like:

```
class B extends A {
    exportToCSV(data: any[], headers: any[], metadata: string) {
        metadata.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

If `metadata` is a required parameter then the call `a.exportToCsv([], [])` would cause a runtime error.  By changing `metadata` to an optional parameter, it is fixed because your implementation of the method in `B` knows that it can't rely on it being passed in:

```
class B extends A {
    exportToCSV(data: any[], headers: any[], metadata?: string) {
        metadata.toUpperCase(); // error, metadata might be undefined
        (metadata || "").toUpperCase(); // okay
    }
}
```

---

So, you should decide whether you really want `B` to be substitutable for `A` (in which case you need the methods to be compatible) or whether you want `B`'s `exportToCSV()` method to require a third parameter (in which case you should think about refactoring so that `B` does not extends `A`... maybe both `B` and `A` can extend something else?  Or maybe `A` could be made generic so `B extends A<T>` for some relevant `T`?).  Anyway, hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATJBvAsAKCUKXgBsQookBBbfI+pCADxgHsAnAFwBVWBhAMoA1ABToQnEAC4kIYAE8A2gF0ANEgAWEDBHZQZcpcoCUtAg0IBffHSLW8twqXKUUjJpwjB0lGrnMWzGxcvIKi4pIGCirqWjp6UUbqkJIR0khQnOwAlsAA5qb+FhYpGBIgAHScrACqMDC6fOQQIsYA3I4M9vT2nfCswJmyMjQAvEjAEADuqK0dAbIVQRw8-MIiMUgq7fi9eKCQsAjIAGLZTADyMJzZAyAkZvTOFNSPxcsha+HliZtx6Lp9LJoiY3hY9j0bAtnq53J5vL4wQwPqswmIfsCkpptACEpjNqU0gB+GSZHL5QqdYpIQnlKq1eqNZpzJAAelZSHQAwA5JxOawkJwNNkoFTiiJaZIkAAfaVIABE8uM9LqDXYTSgLR2C0hCwhRH6gz56TGE2ms219EqKNC60223mewO0DgiCQZyYAHEvLpsvAkTDqAAebhwrw+JDsHEDEjyfHKAB8SPoNq+6Mi8diOMBvzUSAqBajmRk3EpOrsUN1fTILzczHhEaoQcUZNyeUTyaIqbRaVzWfiQMMBIgqQxrYpnZKI7KkhVjPVzPabI5XOAvP5guFovLFgl07SMrliuV1VVTM1czFVk6+qcAyGJub4-bSfGkxmKEvC2tLBWttE9p5sebTLrI7gNPAnCUCAm7ZOwmBwOw4Ajrouz4EAA)