# Is there a way to protect your code from Javascript quirk `Array(length) vs Array(el1,el2,...)` with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm **not looking** for other ways to copy an array. My question is particularly about types.

Typescript has nothing against this kind of code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbGBeGAKAhgJ2wLhjCQCMBTbAbQF0BKVAPhh2wDptSATeYU9LYYABoAbnRSNMAgNTDBABhoAoAN6KY6mKEiwAnqhgUAjIIBMVRWo1boMAB76wpAO4wAgrkw70LHzqWX1axAAG1IWYJAAc3QERHRbGiUAXwtVDU1wGz00I3MAjO07B2c3Dy8fFj8LdKDQ8KiYpHjExRSAegAqRWtYWIB9fXQQbABLSJGwTGC+okQybAgCWfnqMUY0q0zYZfIIPtAAB2zCEvdsT28fYbGJqZmSXaUarZh2CAcHhf2QI7ZObl4-CEogYTGksgU+VqYQi0TeTw07Cg8GwYFepAgrUU-XQRlMtBgbTaMAAzEx3qRbAdSMAoJxsUg+rjDOoqOo6ESYHIYABCPmKDptIA)):

```js
const sum = original_numbers => {
    const numbers_copy = new Array(...original_numbers) // here is the problem
    const res = numbers_copy.reduce((acc,v) => acc+v,0)
    console.log(res)
    return res
}
sum([1,2]) // 3 as expected
sum([1  ]) // 0 !!! And typescript doesn't complain. You can check the playground.
```

Is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the second result be `1`?

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly is "wrong" with this?

Comment: @Liam OP explained what's wrong with it in the code comments

Comment: No they didn't... "here is the problem"...what problem. This all seems to be working as I'd expect it to be

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I'm looking for the way to be warned by the compiler about the fact that the second call to `sum()` **is incorrect**

Comment: How is it "incorrect" exactly?

Comment: Why use new Array() at all?

Comment: @Liam, the author of `sum` method didn't expect that an input array can have the length of 1. Hence the error

Comment: @Liam because `new Array(1,2);` vs `new Array(1);`

Comment: Well that's not typescripts fault. Thats the authors fault

Comment: Are the *types* incorrect?  If not, then what's the question?

Comment: @jcalz the question is how to make the types to be incorrect

Comment: @Liam, yes, it's not Typescript's fault, it's author's fault. And I want to know if typescript can help.

Comment: No. It's valid code and has nothing to do with types. If your question is how do I prevent people writing this, then [as stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63941856/542251) implement a linter. Typescript is a superset of JS that add's types (full stop). All valid JS is automatically valid typescript

Comment: Where, specifically, is the *unexpected* type?  Where, specifically, would you like the compiler to complain?

Comment: It totally has to do with types. The type of `[1]` and `[1, 2]` are both `number[]`, yet the type of `new Array(...[1])` is `any[]` according to TS, and the type of `new Array(...[1, 2])` is `number[]`. Problem is that `any[]` is treated as an acceptable argument to a function expecting `number[]`. Perhaps it ought to be `unknown[]` instead.

Comment: @Liam, For one thing, I could require the minimum array length to be 2. This requirement, of course, with propagate to the rest of the code, which is unacceptable. But in some way we **can** say that it can **be resolved with types**.

Comment: @LionelRowe, hmm... can it lead to something?

Comment: That is how typescript works (All valid JS is automatically valid typescript ). If you disagree with that, [probably raise a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues). Apart from that there isn't anything else to say, working as designed.

Comment: @jcalz, basically, I'd like the `spread` operator to be forbidden. I can't say `Where, specifically` because types **are correct**, and I want them not to be... if it can be done *anywhere at all* that would be OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Array` constructor is problematic enough that there's no "good" way to give it a type definition that works for all use cases.  The standard library's [definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d779a190535e52896cfe5100101173c00b6b8625/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1393) for it looks like

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    new(arrayLength?: number): any[];
    new <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    new <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
}
```

so you are likely to get an array with elements of type [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), which is [intentionally unsound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59315017/2887218), letting you do things that might not be safe without complaint.

If you want a safer version of this you might want to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) (and see [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) if your code is in a module) to use the [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown) type instead:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    new(arrayLength?: number): unknown[];
}
```

At this point, your original code will error like this:

```
const sum_ = (original_numbers: number[]) => {
    const numbers_copy = new Array(...original_numbers) // unknown[]
    const res = numbers_copy.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0) // error!
    // ---------------------------------------> ~~~   ~
    // object is of type unknown
    console.log(res)
    return res
}
```

because `numbers_copy` turns out to maybe not be an array of numbers.  If you want to fix *that*, then you need to change how you call `new Array()` so that the compiler is convinced you're getting a `number[]`.  Possibly like this:

```
const sum = (original_numbers: number[]) => {
    const numbers_copy = new Array(0, 0, ...original_numbers) // number[]
    const res = numbers_copy.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0) // okay
    console.log(res)
    return res
}
sum([1, 2]) // 3 as expected
sum([1]) // 1 as expected
```

That's kind of silly, but adding two more `0`s ensures that you're getting an actual array of numbers, and `0` doesn't affect the sum.  Obviously the "right" thing to do is to stay away from `new Array(...someOtherArray)` and use one of the many well-behaved methods to copy arrays.  You know that, though.

---

The underlying conflict you're having is that you maybe expected TypeScript to save you from this automatically.  The problem is that TypeScript is a valiant effort to give a useful static type system to *JavaScript*, which is dynamically typed and arguably weakly typed.  It can do all sorts of crazy things at runtime, some of which people actually *rely* on.  If TypeScript were to be tightened up so much as to prevent these, it would end up being a legalistic and annoying language to use.

So TypeScript is, for better or worse, [unsound in places](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  This is summed up in [TypeScript Design Non-Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #3: it is *not* a design goal of TypeScript to apply a sound or "provably correct" type system. Instead, the goal is to strike a balance between correctness and productivity.

The particular point at which correctness becomes more or less importance than productivity (or where productivity is actually reduced by having to fix potentially catchable issues at runtime) is subjective and different people have different opinions.  For example, you might want to generalize the problem here where `any` in a library signature hides potential problems, and you'd prefer that `unknown` be used everywhere instead.  There's an open issue for that: [microsoft/TypeScript#26188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26188).  If so, you might want to give that a  and give a compelling description of why you want it.

I've often joked that there should be a TypeScript Unsoundness Support Group to help people deal with the unfortunate reality of the language's type safety limitations. Especially because those of us who have more or less come to accept them can come off as flippant when others run into them for the first time.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngYQPYgDOYUArgmHlMgN4BQyjyIEA7gBRwbYAyEIAczAALAPwAuZqQC2AI2gBKSaRABrEHlYgA2gF0A3HQC+dOggLFkhGQH1kAXmTsqwAaDgAbGyBnyohSR85aD0FBwA+WgYmcyIwKWD-G3MABywHZjY0bix2ADoClzcQT29faEIwgHoq5BV1TR1daMZYyygIQgygv0JkvDS8joATcgh2TgQEABpkADcw+0jEBGQAannZgAZq2ugoKgBCFuQa5ABaS6vrm9u7+6vIgD8XpieTs7xZACsICmRgF08DBkGAsCkUPUNFoTm08B4IHkPHgBOwOpUTh0wKQoCBkOjkMY6NZpDZ2NoAIyzABMul2yAAzMg4F0IAAPCEUCDDYm2ckUumnWpbZCHMWmNrxEkZZxQVzuLw9CqBcpQUIRKJMZCShK9fppbpZdCYXJbbazAp5IoKsqJSpC3UhZpanUExxKpKpLBDbljCYrWYLDUrdabZA7B14VTYWEWeGI5Go9EKTEQbG4-GdIkk-k0wVnJks5DszmQHk5yn52oU5msjl-MumIA)

Answer (score 5):

The Array constructor has problems (including this one). With TSLint, you can use the [prefer-array-literal](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/110) rule to forbid such uses of `new Array`.

For ESLint, you can use [no-array-constructor](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-array-constructor).

To create an array from arguments, consider using `Array.of` instead.

Comment: Thank you. *TSLint* probably **is the way** to do it, but I want to know if I can solve the issue with typescript along.

Comment: Using the Array constructor this way results in the `numbers_copy` array being typed as `any`. TSLint and the `no-unsafe-any` rule will forbid the use of the array items because they're `any`. Nothing wrong with using a linter - I consider using one absolutely essential for any non-trivial project, especially with TS, where one is attempting to write clear, quality code.

Comment: Using the `strict` option in tsconfig (in particular, `noImplicitAny`) will help forbid *some* uses of expressions typed as `any`, but it won't forbid their *creation*, unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately, if you'll check out the playground link you'll see that `noImplicitAny` is on.

Comment: While your answer suggest probably the best way to solve this kind of issues (voted up), I'm inclined to accept jcalz`s answer, as it's closer to the question.