# Why there is no message on wrong implementation of a generic interface

Tags: typescript

I am learning generics in Typescript, I think that implementation should conform to the interface that it belongs to. If it's not, Typescript should give some error messages.

So I wrote a very short code and didn't implement it correctly: I didn't specify the param and its type in `add` function, but nothing happened, I don't know why, here is my code in typescript:

```
interface Backpack<Type> {
    add: (obj: Type) => void;
    get: () => Type;
}
const backpackFunction:Backpack<string> = {
    add(){
        return undefined;
    },
    get(){
        return "string";
    }
}
```

I think that typescript should tell me that I missed the param of `add` function.

So is that a bug or there is still some other knowledge that I don't know.

Please help me Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be surprising but there is nothing wrong with your implementation of `add()`.  See the TypeScript FAQ entry ["Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) for details.

It is almost always safe to pass a function more parameters than it is expecting, because in JavaScript these parameters will generally be ignored.  So you can can safely make this call:

```
backpackFunction.add("hello"); // no error
```

and nothing bad will happen at runtime.  The implementation of `backpackFunction.add()` will return `undefined` no matter what, if anything, is passed into it.

---

One might make the argument that this sort of thing is still probably an error, but it turns out that there are lots of situations that look identical to the compiler where you really don't want an error.  It is idiomatic JavaScript to write callback functions that take fewer parameters than may be passed to them.  For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(x => 1 / x); // no error
```

That's a completely normal use of [an array's `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  But that callback `x => 1 / x` only declares a single input parameter, even though `map()` will call it with three:

```
[1, 2, 3].map((...args) => console.log(args));
/*
[LOG]: [1, 0, [1, 2, 3]]
[LOG]: [2, 1, [1, 2, 3]]
[LOG]: [3, 2, [1, 2, 3]]
*/
```

So unless you want to force people to write this:

```
[1, 2, 3].map((x, ugh, iDontCare) => 1 / x),
```

it turns out that you probably don't want to require function implementations to declare as many parameters as they will be called with.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEKINYAdMB4AqAnlhAHzIDeAsAFDLJwAmjAXMgBQD2ARgFZtESASmQBecgDdOwRgG5a9AOYQwbdiPHJBEeTQC+tBJxABnMMm6YcCDADEAriARhgxtuhvWMuM1FCLyUUoFBmZ1YLp6ZCgVeygQZEdGCBhQCDkQvQAaEOUwcOpI+hiwOISAIl9-ct16A31aWktPTAcnF2MAOiZGdnKACwgAGyHOcqFdWgBtAEYs5AAmeYBmAF1OgFs4LHYADzFyGeQAemRdidpjgCpkAEEoKDhCXBB7De5oUk3tl7ePqFI7BCCDgI2aGBgIDUElB9ggbFe72g81AyV2CL+yIYDyeGKRUCmqw05ER-3mYH6wBM90UAH42HAQIQQkI8f9CcgrscQtM5osVustjt2J1RXAoIoTMTkEZTJwhhBOqNFOxxZKhBcaNdpgAZADyAHFVmxZvMAAzzU385BrVa6w3G5BTJbIPlWl22+1Gk3LeYu90Cu00Lm0IA)

Comment: Mr jcalz, if I give `add` function an `any` type param, why is that still ok? `add(obj:any){ return undefined; }`, because I set the generic to be `string` not `any`

Comment: Because `any` is intentionally unsound as a way to allow for gradual typing; see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313928/is-this-behavior-of-a-typescript-type-system-bug) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for this, we can however engineer a scenario where not passing in a type parameter will generate an error, using default generic type arguments and conditional types.