# Why is there no type error in this TypeScript code?

Tags: typescript

I tested some assignability of functions and found that there is no type error in this code:

```
type Foo = (a: number) => number;
const foo: Foo = () => 123;
```

I intended that function must accept single number type parameter and return number.
But function foo does not accept parameter. So I expected that there should be type error, but this code can be compiled.

Why does TypeScript accept this code? I cannot find related information inside documentation.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions

Comment: What does "must accept a number" mean to you? How can you distinguish from the outside whether a function does "accept" the number passed to it or not? A function not declaring a parameter accepts *any* value as its argument (and immediately discards it).

Comment: Because that's not a type error _in the JavaScript_; functions don't need to declare parameters to receive arguments. You'd only have a problem if the implementation required additional parameters that weren't guaranteed by the interface, or if it needed to receive a non-`number` parameter.

Comment: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parametershttps://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: Also related: [Why there is no message on wrong implementation of a generic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67830601)