# How do I specify an optional number and type of extra parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript

So I have a real world example.  I have created a utility function which wraps the 'findAll' method in a nest.js service.   I want be able to easily add a singleOrFail method to any service like so:

```js
export class UsersService {
  async findAll(query:any) {
    return; // impl 
  }
    
  async singleOrFail(query: any) {
    return await performSingleOrFail(this, query);
  }
}
```

Where the performSingleOrFail functionality looks like this:

```js
interface FindCapable {
  findAll(conditions: any): Promise<any>;
}

export const performSingleOrFail = async (
  parent: FindCapable,
  conditions: any
) => {
  const result = await parent.findAll(conditions);
  if (!result || result.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Record not found');
  }
  if (result.length > 1) {
    throw new Error('More than one record found');
  }
  return result[0];
};
```

My problem is that the "findAll" method often has arbitrary extra arguments, for example a ClientSession, or a flag to retrieve hidden fields.  I don't know or care what the extra arguments (if any) are, I just want to pass them through the performSingleOrFail function to the findAll method if they exist.
eg:

```js
export class UsersService {
  async findAll(query: any, someOtherArbitraryArgument: boolean) {
    console.log("This is important: ", someOtherArbitraryArgument);
    return; // impl
  }

  async singleOrFail(query: any, someOtherArbitraryArgument: boolean) {
    return await performSingleOrFail(this, query, someOtherArbitraryArgument);
  }
}
```

How would I specify that interface?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those extra arguments are always same for each service (e.g. only `someOtherArbitraryArgument` will be passed for `UsersService`) or they can be different?

Comment: ① Could you please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without undeclared/missing types or values from private or external libraries?  And without any unrelated problems when compiled in `--strict` mode?  This will remove distractions and allow others to get to work on a suggested answer. Right now I'm seeing errors about missing `userModel`, `NotFoundException`, and annotation on `conditions`. ②  Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpKVpN) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer (after you [edit] your code or let me do it). If not what am I missing

Comment: @jcalz thank you, and apologies for the incomplete code.  I was looking at it all wrong, trying to separate the first argument, when I didn't need to do any such thing.  Yes, please write up an answer so that I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need is to use a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead of a regular parameter for `conditions`, and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_function_calls) that parameter into function calls:

```
interface FindCapable {
  findAll(...conditions: any): Promise<any>;
}

export const performSingleOrFail = async (
  parent: FindCapable,
  ...conditions: any
) => {
  const result = await parent.findAll(...conditions);
  if (!result || result.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Record not found');
  }
  if (result.length > 1) {
    throw new Error('More than one record found');
  }
  return result[0];
};
```

Now your function allows any number of arguments instead of always exactly one:

```
export class UsersService {
  async findAll(query: any, someOtherArbitraryArgument: boolean) {
    console.log("This is important: ", someOtherArbitraryArgument);
    return //this.userModel.find(query).exec();
  }

  async singleOrFail(query: any, someOtherArbitraryArgument: boolean) {
    return await performSingleOrFail(this, query, someOtherArbitraryArgument); // okay
  }
}
```

Note that these are not strongly typed; you were using [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) for `conditions`, and I'm still using the `any` type for `conditions`.  In neither case will the compiler catch a problem with the *types* of the arguments (and now it won't catch a problem with the *number* of arguments either), because `any` is intentionally loose (see [Is this behavior of "any" a TypeScript Type System Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59313928/2887218) ).  Since that's not the focus of the question it's out of scope to go into it here.  Just know that there might be more work to do if you care about type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-tlr2JZB+gMQIMakPV5ms9qdZAOWDONzbWd+ALMJuCC2L-ur-N2qAOzfbm6UAenuYATPWdakgA1nAEhggYVBAA)